# Need help understanding a specific type of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am still relatively new to coding. I've been doing this for less than a year and most of the basics I completely understand now. However, every now and then I come across a type of for loop that I can't get my head around.

It usually goes like this:

`x for x in list if x in otherList`

I completley understand for loops and if statements. But that particular line of code always confuses me. Would anyone be able to provide a detailed explanation of what actually is happening there, please?

Comment: it's called list comprehension, google should give you plenty of reading material! good luck

Comment: That is not a valid statement in itself, it usually within [ ... ] or { ... } or ( ... ), it then is a list / dict / set comprehension or a a generator expression, etc.

Comment: Sorry, no. You first. Please explain each element of the code you have posted until you get stuck.

Comment: Please read [the official tutorial on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a *list comprehension* if it's in brackets `[]`:

This:

```py
new_list = [x for x in my_list if x in other_list]
```

Is equivalent to this:

```py
new_list = []
for x in my_list:
    if x in other_list:
        new_list.append(x)
```

---

If it's in parentheses `()` it's called a generator:

This:

```py
new_list = (x for x in my_list if x in other_list)
```

Is sort of equivalent to this:

```py
def foo():
    for x in my_list:
        if x in other_list:
            yield x

new_list = foo()
```

You might want to read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) to understand more about generators and yielding functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is used within a list comprehension and the if statement acts as a filter.

You may begin with a list of all numbers from 0-9:

`mynums = range(10)`

But then you might want only the even numbers in a new list:

```
myevennums=[]
for i in mynums:
    if mynums%2 ==0:
       myevennums.append(i)
```

That works but so many keystrokes

So python allows list comprehensions:

`myevennums = [i for i in mynums if i%2==0]`

The condition could be anything, including membership in another list:

`evens_to_20 = list(range(0,21,2))`

Then you could create a list with the elements of your list that are also in the other list:

```
myevennums = [i for i in mynums if i in evens_to_20]
```

In general, when you see a statement like that you can always expand it as:

```py
Y_comprehension = [i for i in X if condition(i)] 
# the same as
Y_loop=[]
for i in X:
    if condition(i):
        Y_loop.append(i)
assert Y_comprehension == Y_loop
```

If the condition really is very simple, the list-comprehension is usually the better choice. If it starts to get complicated, you probably want the loop or an intermediate function `def condition(item): ...`